# Вывод ромба в консоли C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Вывожу ромб в консоли таким способом:

```
class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 6;
        int y = 6;
        int x1 = 6;
        int y1 = 6;
        int size = 6;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {

            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + i);
            Console.WriteLine("*");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(x - i, y + size);
            Console.WriteLine("*");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x - i, y + i);
            Console.WriteLine("*");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + i);
            Console.WriteLine("*");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x + i, y + size);
            Console.WriteLine("*");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x + i, y + i);
            Console.WriteLine("*");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        { 
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x1, y1 + i);
            Console.WriteLine("*");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x1 + i, y1 - size);
            Console.WriteLine("*");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x1 + i, y1 - i);
            Console.WriteLine("*");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(x1, y1 + i);
            Console.WriteLine("*");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x1 - i, y1 - size);
            Console.WriteLine("*");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x1 - i, y - i);
            Console.WriteLine("*");


        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Но получается не ромб, а что-то вроде этого:

> ```
>  * * * * *
>   *    *
>     *
>     *
>   *   *
> * * * * *
> ```

А должно быть это :

```
>         *
>       *   *
>     * * * * *
>       *   *
>         *
```

Comment: заметь, что нижний треугольник у тебя такой же как верхний для ожидаемого результата: попробуй просто поменять местами циклы

Comment: @Grundy, ничего не изменилось

Comment: не может быть, у тебя же по разному позиции высчитываются

Comment: Можете попробовать и убедиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну почти.

Вы должны всё время помнить, что у вас `y`-координата в консоли отсчитывается вниз, а не вверх. Из-за этого путаница.

У вас `(x, y)` — верхняя опорная точка, поэтому нужно

```
int y = 0;
```

Аналогично, `(x1, y1)` — нижняя опорная точка, поэтому

```
int y = 12;
```

Ну и несколько мелких опечаток: во втором цикле у вас `Console.SetCursorPosition(x1, y1 + i);`, но раз вы отсчитываете вверх от нижней опорной точки, то нужен минус. (В двух местах.) И ещё вы в том же цикле один раз по ошибке используете `y` вместо `y1`.

С исправленными этими ошибками у меня получилось такое:

```
      *
     ***
    * * *
   *  *  *
  *   *   *
 *    *    *
 ***********
 *    *    *
  *   *   *
   *  *  *
    * * *
     ***
      *
```

Comment: вот слова вроде знакомые, но что написано совсем не понимаю :-D

Comment: @Grundy: Вот так даже? :)

Comment: Ага :-) в код не вникал - а по объяснению, понятно что, что-то в коде :)

Comment: @Grundy, а не подскажете, как зафиксировать положение фигур(треугольник и квадрат перемещаются по консоли, когда их координаты совпадут, нужно зафиксировать их положение)