# Программа должна печатать ромб одним из значков (* или + или #)

Tags: c#

Компилятор никакой ошибки не выдает, но массив не печатает. Что не так?

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PROJECT2
{
   class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Введите 1, чтобы ромб был напечатан символом '*', ");
        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Введите 2, чтобы ромб был напечатан символом '+', ");
        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Введите 3, чтобы ромб был напечатан символом '#'. ");

        int inputNum = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        List<string> forRhombus = new List<string> ();


        switch (inputNum) 
        {
        case 1:
            string a = "*";
            Console.WriteLine ("Введите нечетную длину стороны ромба от 5 до 15: ");
            int lenght1 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
            int p = 1;

            if ((lenght1 >= 5) && (lenght1 <= 15))
            {   
                for (int x = 0; x < lenght1; x++)
                {
                    forRhombus.Add (" ");
                }
                if (lenght1 % 2 != 0)
                {   

                    for (int y = 0; y < lenght1; y++)
                    {

                        if (y == lenght1 / 2.0 + 0.5) 
                        {   
                            forRhombus [y] = a;
                            Console.WriteLine (forRhombus);

                        }

                        if ((p < y) && (p < lenght1)) 
                        {
                            forRhombus [y + p] = a;
                            forRhombus [y - p] = a;
                            p += 1;
                        }   

                        Console.WriteLine (forRhombus);
                    }
                }   
            }
            break;



        case 2:
            string b = "+";
            Console.WriteLine ("Введите нечетную длину стороны ромба от 5 до 15: ");
            int lenght2 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

            break;

        case 3:
            string c = "#";
            Console.WriteLine ("Введите нечетную длину стороны ромба от 5 до 15: ");
            int lenght3 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

            break;

        }      

    }
}
```

Comment: Да были тут уже фигурные задачи.

Comment: `int inputNum = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine ());`

Comment: Сделайте так чтобы программа работала без пользовательского ввода. Уберите лишние ветки, чтобы мы не гадали в какой ветке ошибка. Попробуйте локализовать проблему: проверяйте результат каждой строки и определите какая строка ведет себя не так как нужно. В общем, создайте [МСВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод ромба в консоли C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628541/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-c)

Comment: @defaultlocale Пользовательский ввод - часть задачи.

Comment: @nick_n_a я на сайте нашел сам, у нас  школе нет C#

Comment: @nick_n_a я несколько дней назад сам начал изучать C#

Comment: @Михаил но не часть этого конкретного вопроса. С вводом же проблем нет, зачем его включать в вопрос?

Comment: Как минимум, `if (y == lenght1 / 2 + 0.5)` не будет работать, так как `lenght1 / 2` выполняет целочисленное деление. Замените `2` на `2.0`. `forRhombus[y - p] = a;` индекс выходит за пределы массива, когда y = 0, а p = 1.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine (forRhombus)` — здесь индекс не забыт?

Answer (score 2):

Разбивайте свой код на функции (методы), которые выполняют одну функцию. В вашем варианте можно разбить так:

- основной метод `Main()`;
- метод с меню;
- метод с созданием ромба;
- метод с выводом ромба.

Некоторые замечания по вашему коду:

- для переноса каретки (вывод в консоли с новой строки) можно использовать специальный символ `\n`, а не дублировать лишний раз `WriteLine()`. Например: `Console.WriteLine("\n <- Новая строка -> \n")`;
- для таких простых задач как запись и чтение данных по индексу, расточительно использовать коллекции, уж тем более с типом `string` (я про `List<string> forRhombus`), куда правильнее будет использовать массив `char`;
- так как ромб, хоть и из символов, является каким-никаким рисунком, то есть имеет высоту и ширину, то логичнее и проще для понимания использовать двумерный массив (матрицу, `char[,]`), а не одномерный, хотя можно и его. Вариант с одномерным массивом приведён ниже.
- `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` действительно преобразует строку с числом в тип `int`. Ну а если пользователь введёт букву или вообще ничего не введёт? Приложение крашнется, так как символ не удалось преобразовать в число. Для таких случаев обычно используется метод [`Int32.TryParse(String, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx), который возвращает `true` при успешном преобразовании строки в число и `false` в противном случае. Также второй параметр является out-параметром, что очень удобно. Изучите этот момент, он сильно поможет при работе с пользовательскими данными, которые вводятся от руки;
- для вывода массива или списка понадобится написать собственный метод с циклом (или использование анонимных методов и LINQ, но пока не лезьте в эти сложные темы), так что ваш вариант `Console.WriteLine(forRhombus)` просто не будет работать;
- не забывайте про секцию `default` в операторе `switch()` - это важно.

Моя реализация рисования ромба основывается на том, что у ромба все углы равны и необходимо нарисовать его закрашенным, а не только контур. Ниже приведён метод, принимающий размер стороны ромба, символ для ромба и для заднего фона, который возвращает одномерный массив:

```
private static char[] GetFillRhombus(int size, char foreground, char background = ' ')
{
    if (size > 1)
    {
        char[] map = new char[Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow((size * 2 - 1), 2))];

        // Заполнение всего массива задним фоном
        for (int i = 0; i < map.Length; i++)
        {
            map[i] = background;
        }

        // Заполнение верхней части ромба с серединой
        for (int i = 1; i < size * 2; i += 2)
        {
            int startPosition = size * i - i;
            for (int j = startPosition; j < startPosition + i; j++)
            {
                map[j] = foreground;
            }
        }

        // Заполнение нижней части ромба без середины
        for (int i = 0, j = size - 2 - i; j >= 0; i++, j--)
        {
            int middlePosition = (size + i) * (size * 2) - (i + 1);
            for (int k = middlePosition - j; k < middlePosition + j + 1; k++)
            {
                map[k] = foreground;
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Далее этот массив надо вывести пользователю на экран:

```
private static void PrintRhombus(char[] map)
{
    if (map != null)
    {
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(map.Length));
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < map.Length; i++, j++)
        {
            Console.Write(map[i]);
            if (j == size - 1)
            {
                j = -1;
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Использование сводится к 1-2 строчкам кода:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] rhombus = GetFillRhombus(20, '#', '.');
    PrintRhombus(rhombus);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Результат, ромб со стороной в 20 символов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Михаил если вам ответ помог - отметьте его как правильный.